# How to detect user has stopped typing in TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart, delay, textfield

I am using a `TextField` under which `onChanged` function

I am calling my code but the issue right now is the code gets execute everytime a new word is either entered or deleted.

what I am looking for is **how to recognize when a user has stopped typing**.

means adding some delay or something like that.

I have tried adding `delay` also using `Future.delayed` function but that function also gets executed n number of times.

```
TextField(
   controller: textController,
   onChanged: (val) {
            if (textController.text.length > 3) {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 450), () {
                 //code here
              });
            }
            setState(() {});
          },
 )
```

Comment: are you familiar with rxdart? or with streams in general?

Comment: I have seen some examples related to it, but not used it till now. Do you have some example you can share related to this use case?

Comment: see https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform, and use [debounce](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_transform#debounce-debouncebuffer) stream transformer - the docs say: *"Prevents a source stream from emitting too frequently by dropping or collecting values that occur within a given duration."*

Comment: thankyou @pskink do you know where can I find an example for that package. I guess there is too less document available.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-async/Stream/transform.html

Comment: Hi @pskink can you post some code example on how to use it with TextField, I am right now clueless on how to use it.

Comment: see https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller - inside `onChanged` simply call `StreamController.add` method

Comment: as simple as: `StreamController<String> controller = StreamController();` then inside `initState` method: `controller.stream.transform(debounce(Duration(seconds: 1))).listen((s) => print('you typed: [$s]'));` and use it in your widget: `TextField(onChanged: controller.add),`

Comment: Thanks a lot @pskink that works seamlessly.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: @pskink Hi mate, over last few months, I have seen you providing excellent solutions but only in comment, why don't you write them down as an answer, you would have easily gained +10k reputation.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad i am too lazy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink

I was able to achieve the functionality I was looking for.

import  stream_transform package in your `pubspec.yaml`

`stream_transform: ^0.0.19`

```
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart';

StreamController<String> streamController = StreamController();

@override
void initState() {
  streamController.stream
    .transform(debounce(Duration(milliseconds: 400)))
    .listen((s) => _validateValues());

  super.initState();
}

//function I am using to perform some logic
_validateValues() {
  if (textController.text.length > 3) {
     // code here
  }else{
     // some other code here
  }
}
```

TextField code

```
TextField(
   controller: textController,
   onChanged: (val) {
        streamController.add(val);
     },
)
```

Comment: instead of `textController.text.length > 3` use `Stream.where()` method (before calling `Stream.listen()`)

Comment: you mean like this `.where((String val) => userHandleController.text.length > 3 ? true : false)`

Comment: but then how would I pass true or false to `_validateValues` function as I need to execute two code , in `if` and in `else`

Comment: What is mean debounce function on here ? It is not defined.  @VickySalunkhe

Answer (score 3):

I find something so lighter in this [link](https://medium.com/fabcoding/implementing-search-in-flutter-delay-search-while-typing-8508ea4004c6)

it define this class

```
class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;

  Timer? _timer;

  Debouncer({this.milliseconds=500});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != _timer) {
      _timer!.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}
```

this sample will help you more

```
TextField(
     decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search'),
     onChanged: (string) {
       _debouncer.run(() {
       print(string);
       //perform search here
       });
     },
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I also required flutter async.

```
//pubspec.yaml
stream_transform: ^2.0.0

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart';

StreamController<String> streamController = StreamController();

// In init function
streamController.stream
    .debounce(Duration(seconds: 1))
    .listen((s) => { 
       // your code 
     });

// In build function
TextField(
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
   controller: messageController,
   onChanged: (val) {
     myMetaRef.child("isTyping").set(true);
     streamController.add(val);
     },
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty late. In my case I needed to check the availability of an email during the sign up process and needed to show the relevant message to user when the user stopped typing the email in the textfield. You need to create a timer and reset it every time the user types something inside the textfield. Here's the code:

```
Timer? _checkTypingTimer;

startTimer() {
    _checkTypingTimer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 600), () {//set your desired duration
      //perform your logic here
      //i was calling the method here which checks if the email is available or not
    });
  }

resetTimer() {
    _checkTypingTimer?.cancel();
    startTimer();
  }
```

Now call this `resetTimer` method inside the `onChanged` method of your textfield. And don't forget to import `dart:async`

**Note**: The answer given above with the *medium link*, the "debouncer one", may needlessly invoke your code several times