# How to implement infinite scroll pagination the right way

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a search request but the data returned comes with a pagination type. I have in my `onchanged` function in my TextField so that whenever I type something, it makes a get request. The first letter I type works fine but when I type again, nothing happens.

This is what I have in my `onChanged` function

```
onChanged: (value) {
      _pagingController.addPageRequestListener(
      (pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey, val.trim());
    },
   );
 },
```

Below is my _fetchPageFunction

```
Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey, String searchParam) async {
    final results = await searchRepo.getCareers(
          isSearching: true,
          searchParam: searchParam,
          token: token,
          page: pageKey,
        );
      hasNextPage = results['hasNextPage'];
      newItems.clear();
      newItems = results['schools'];
      print(newItems.length);
      if (!hasNextPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error.toString();
    }
  }
```

Below is my UI

```
PagedListView<int, dynamic>(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  pagingController: _pagingController,
                  builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<dynamic(
                    itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: InitialsAvatar(name: item.name),
                        title: Text(
                          item.name ?? 'n/a',
                          style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          item.category,
                          style: theme.textTheme.labelMedium,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

I tried removing the pageRequestLister after the `_fetchPage` funtion but it did not work.
Is there any way I can do this? If this is not possible, is there any other package that can work for me?

Comment: most likely you need to add some kind of "debounce" mechanism that prevents sending the requests on each key stroke, something like https://gist.github.com/pskink/c4d3615d93ba77ef16016aaca21e0f77#file-foo_search-dart-L72

Comment: please include a complete example, as others will be able to help you more accurately. The snippet should be runnable

Comment: Please i have made some edit for clearer understanding

Comment: This is what helped me with what I needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606863/17730070

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `_pagingController.refresh();` inside your `onChanged()`.

```
onChanged: (value) {
      _pagingController.refresh();
      _pagingController.addPageRequestListener(
      (pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey, val.trim());
    },
   );
 },
```

Comment: This kind of works but it is fetching a lot of data...for example one item is appearing like 5 times..and also the previous data I got are not clearing, they are adding up to the recent data I am fetching. If only I can add some kind of mechanism which checks if the user is done typing, then i will make the request

Comment: Can you post full code of this screen?

Comment: @Samuel "If only I can add some kind of mechanism which checks if the user is done typing," so have you tried the code I gave you?

Comment: @pskink yes it does but it is displaying one item like 6 times